# Version of MySQL compatibility with flyway

Tags: java, flyway

I needed to upgrade Flyway version from 7.5.0 to 9.22.3 and now I have this error when trying to start my application

> Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: MySQL 8.1

What version of MySQL is compatible with flyway 9.22.3

Previously I had this dependency in my **build.gradle** file

```
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:7.5.0'
```

and spring boot version 2.5.2

But I upgraded spring boot to version 3.1.5 and I got these errors

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.configureProperties(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:201)

The following method did not exist:

    'org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.failOnMissingLocations(boolean)'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/Users/adriian/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.1.5/42a5b2ee98f700fba8d8c88d4af7b23266f1de0f/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class

The called method's class, org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/adriian/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/7.5.0/c035645a32956109b8c602a90d0fa79cf2354ba5/flyway-core-7.5.0.jar!/org/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration: file:/Users/adriian/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/7.5.0/c035645a32956109b8c602a90d0fa79cf2354ba5/flyway-core-7.5.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration and org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration
```

I found that the solution will be upgrading the version of Flyway to at least 9
and after adding these dependencies

```
  implementation group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '9.22.2'
  implementation group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-mysql', version: '9.22.2'
```

I got an error about MySQL version support

Comment: Which ersion of MySQL are you using?

Comment: https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/mysql-184127601.html

Comment: I am using 8.1
mysql> SELECT VERSION()
    -> ;
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.1.0     |

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace. Assuming you have included the `flyway-mysql` module, I think this should not produce this error, if the module was loaded, it would _log_ a warning that you need to upgrade Flyway, but still work. As far as I'm aware, this exception is only thrown when there is no `DatabaseType` implementation that supports this database, and for MySQL that would only happen if the module is not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would depend on whether you're using flyway CLI or Java. If you are using Java, you will need to include the `flyway-mysql` dependency as described in the documentation: https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/mysql-184127601.html

Comment: I`ve added that dependency , but i still see the same error

Comment: @user Could you post the code you used to include the dependency?

Comment: It was fixed, by closing and reopening Intellij Idea, thanks for your response